# Query To Show All Users Who Have Multiple Managers

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a database that holds user information.  I need a way to find out what users have multiple managers.  Below is a subset of data to illustrate the data structure.

Using MS SQL Server 2016 what would be a query to show me all userid and managerid where for each user the count of managerid > 1?

```
Declare @@Test Table
(
    userid varchar(100),
    mngrid varchar(100)
)


Insert Into @@Test Values ('abc-413', '619232'), ('abc-413', '39021'), ('xyz-999', '39021')

Select * FROM @@Test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the [`GROUP BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and the [`HAVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause to filter the Table down to only users with multiple managers like so:

```
SELECT userid
FROM Test
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(mngrid) > 1
```

Also I don't think `@@Test` is valid syntax (though I'm unable to test right now) so my example just uses a regular Table, but you can replace it with your actual Table name.

Comment: That syntax works thank you.  The ``@@Table`` is a Table Valued Param, I use it in place of temp tables all the time :)

Comment: @JamesMandatory No prob! `@TableName` is a table-valued parameter. I've never seen `@@TableName` before, but perhaps that's a global table-valued parameter?